# How to access common namespaces for XML parsing

Tags: c#

I have stored my common namespaces used in my Linq to Xml parsing in a config file.  Where is the best place to access them in my application? Put them in my base class? Create a Config Class that I can call (call namespaces via accessors), ? What would be deemed a good practice here.  I currently have about 7 namespaces.

Thanks,

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the requirement? You currently have the namespaces in a config file which allows you to change them without recompiling the application. If you feel this is useful, I would keep them in the file and, as you suggest, create a type to hold the values at runtime which can be passed as a dependency to any code which needs to know about the namespaces.

If however, you expect these namespaces to fixed for ever, it may be reasonable to hard code them into your base class or wherever else in the source code makes sense (this could also be done using embedded resources rather than string literals).

This latter option would have the benefit of reducing unnecessary noise in your config file and the need for the added dependency type, but I would suggest that, in most cases, it's probably just as well to use the config file pattern regardless. Yes it may be a little extra clutter, but in this business things that you think will never change have a habit of changing.

Also, you say that you *currently* have 7 namespaces. This suggests to me that you think you may have more or less in the future. For this reason, it sounds like you probably should be using the config file pattern.